# Make cell height in one column not affect other columns within the same row in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have done a schedule in Google Spreadsheet. I set text wrapping to wrap. The problem is that when I write something in column A and the row in column A gets expanded to fit all text all other columns with the same row line up with that expanded size. I want to wrap text in just the column that I'm writing and not affect any other columns. How do I fix this?

Can I somehow isolate one column to not affect the other columns? Or is there another solution?

This picture describes what I want to achieve:

```
      A           B
| some text |___________|
| goes here |___________|
|___________|___________|
|___________|
|___________|
```

Answer (score 1):

If you select the three rows in Column A and use the Format / Merge Cells / Merge All applied     option, you get something which looks like that.

There is an example of how it looks in this sheet:    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sg-Rn_ZcNic8rpFek9DTlKtU-XuS4rukeZoyeQ4aLJA/edit?usp=sharing

The disadvantage is that it only works when you don't have any content in those rows in Column A.    And it can make using some other spreadsheet features difficult.   But if layout is most important to you, then it will work.

Comment: I figured this out myself. But what I really were looking for was that the rows would come like this automatically without the need to use merge. So that I just needed to write in text and get the result automatically(without the need to calculate how many rows i needed for my text).

Comment: I'm afraid that's really not how spreadsheets work.   Perhaps you should consider using a table in a Docs file instead of a spreadsheet.